# Argparse Namespace not working on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, argparse

In my python3 program I start a new process. Behold my code below:

```
import argparse
import threading
from threading import Thread
args = argparse.Namespace(project=[data], parameter1=True, parameter2=False)
                p = Process(target=program, args=(args,))
                p.start()
```

As you can see I am passing arguments with it and it works great on Linux. But on Windows the arguments are not passed and it causes the program to malfunction.

The parameters passed are:

```
 error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork parent_pid=16316 pipe_handle=700
```

(It's a cross platform tool)

Any ideas for a work-around?

Comment: have you printed `args` ?

Comment: yes, it only contains the name of the script

Comment: Who or what is raising that error.  It looks sort of like a `argparse` message, but you didn't provide the `usage` part.  Plus if you've already formed a `Namespace` you aren't parsing a `sys.argv`.  Other than using `argparse` to create a `Namespace` object, I don't see what this has to do with `argparse`.